# Cortar primer y último carácter de un String de longitud aleatoria en bash

Tags: bash, shell

Mi idea es hacer un Stript para eliminar el primer carácter y el último de una cadena que me da otro programa que funciona concurrentemente.

Las cadenas que me da el programa siempre van a empezar con un `*` y van a terminar con un `;` por lo que mi idea era hacer lo siguiente:

```
./Programaparalelo.sh | cut -d* -f2 | cut -d1 -F";"
```

Pero no funciona.

Sin embargo sí me funcionan los `cut` por separado. Puedo quitar así el primero o el último pero no los dos.

No se me ocurre nada. Si alguno tuviera alguna idea me seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: No queda claro. El programa tira siempre _lineas_ que empiezan con * y  terminan con ; ? Y quieres eliminar esos caracteres ? (o no los estas incluyendo?) Estamos seguros de que esos caracters no van a aparecer dentro de la cadena? Ayudaría mucho que des un ejemplo (salida del programa, resultado esperado)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es eliminar el primer y el último carácter de una cadena, usa:

```
sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//'
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ echo '*hola que tal;' | sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//'
hola que tal
```

---

Si quieres tener más seguridad, puedes validar que sea `*` el primer carácter y `;` el último con:

```
sed -e 's/^*//' -e 's/;$//'
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ echo '*hola que tal;' | sed -e 's/^*//' -e 's/;$//'
hola que tal
$ echo 'hola que tal' | sed -e 's/^*//' -e 's/;$//'
hola que tal
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes construir algo similar a substring con el siguiente script:

```
#!/bin/bash

original="-Quitando guiones-"

inicio=1
longitud=$((${#original} - 2))
final=${original:${inicio}:${longitud}}

echo $final
```

Guárdalo con algún nombre, dale permisos de ejecución ... y prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Si la cadena esta en una variable puedes:

```
$ var="*variable de prueba;"

$ var=${var#\*}                # elimina el asterisco

$ var=${var%;}                 # elimina el `;`

$ echo "$var"
```